# "Uncaught TypeError: window.getDeviceDetails is not a function" RazorPay Integration with android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, razorpay

Integrated Razorpay Android Standard SDK. When I select success with testing mode account in android studio (JAVA), this error is displayed on log console:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: window.getDeviceDetails is not a function"
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this response is too late but anyway.

I have faced the same issue as you mentioned.

after searching a while found that while setting image in the checkout method
the image maximum size should not exceed 512*512 after rectifying this everything worked fine.

```
checkout.setImage(R.drawable.logo);
```

source

[this is the source](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-android-sample-app/issues/136)